# How to add XP support to a C# application VS 2012

Tags: c#

I've google allready this but I don't have those options in my project properties. that's what I have":
[image: no]

And this is what I need to have:
[image]

Comment: What do you think that option does, what _are_ you trying to do?

Comment: You're looking at properties for C++ projects, not C#.  For C# projects, all you need to do to support XP is to select a framework version < 4.5

Comment: I'm trying to run an application on Windows XP that run's ok on Windows 7...

Comment: @ZaraGheorghe You've confused yourself by finding something on the internet which is talking about C++.  All you need to do is to go to the project properties, and chose the 4.0 framework on the 'Application' page

Comment: It's more the .NET Framework you need to support rather than the OS. If you have an XP machine that doesn't have .NET 4 on it but your Windows 7 does, then your XP machine will not support a .NET 4 application but your Windows 7 will. (As Will Dean says be sure to select a Framework of <=4.0)

Comment: @WillDean allready tryied this...this didnt solve my problem with 3.5 version of .NetFramework.

Comment: @ZaraGheorghe is .NET 3.5 installed on the XP Machine?

Comment: you tagged c# but your screenshot are about c++

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at properties for C++ code. The settings in your screenshots are simply not applicable to your C# code.

For C# you need to target a .net version that is supported on XP. So you need to target .net version 4 or earlier. and you need to make sure that the .net framework that you target is deployed to any machine that will run your program.